# Where to find documentation of Grub modules, such as `datehook`?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/323487/109900) I found an example of using the `datehook` Grub module. But I could neither find documentation of it nor other Grub modules. Where can I find it?

(I'd like to work around the limitations of saving the default menu option with LVM/RAID: I'd like to set up Grub to *"if time <= preset time then boot option 1, else option 2".* Setting the preset time to *now + 1* minute or so would allow to change the boot option just for a single reboot.)